# Set up connection to non-existent DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datasource

I'm wanting to set up some DB connections via config files - one local, some remote. Using the Data Source wizard, I am prompted to set up a new connection using the Add Connection window. But these DBs don't yet exist, or are not accessible from my dev PC, and it seems to require to be able to connect to them to let me proceed.

Is there a way around this, or do I just need to manually put the details in my config file instead in this case? I'm not very familiar using Data Sources rather than just manually setting up connection objects.

Comment: sorry, could you please explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @icbytes if this is the case, then you are right, he has to go with the approach you have defined above.. i don't think he can do it in any other way.

Comment: @icbytes yes you understand it right. I'd also be interested when using the wizard, exactly where and how it stores these connections (then I can more easily add them manually)

Comment: Post as an answer or is this comment ok for You ?

Comment: An answer would be good.

Answer (score 1):

As the op asked me for, I just post my deleted comment as answer, not lurking for any points.

If You want to use the visual studio wizard and create connection-objects, adapters, and all the generated stuff in advance to have them later, but the targeted db's are either locally not existent or remotely not reachable, there is no possibility as far as I know. Either You get the database-connection running properly and talk to the admin to register Your user for them or You ask for a schema of those databases and recreate this stuff locally Yourself in a sqlexpress-db OR only a simple dataset ( db is better for using the wizard ).

Answer (score 0):

I can see why a developer might want to do this, as I'm facing a similar problem with a development PC that hasn't got Access (I couldn't install it due to a mixture of versions of Office apps that weren't compatible). What I've done is I've created a static utility class that creates the required database (via the ADO Catalog class) and its tables, which uses the currently-configured connection string. The only problem is I need the connection string for this class, which AFAIK requires the database to exist in the first place. At the moment I do this by creating an empty Access database using the "ODBC Data Sources" utility, use that to set up the connection string in my application, and then delete the database before running the application and creating it programatically.